# Minimum number of steps to determine the following function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, optimization, induction, recreational-mathematics

The problem is the following:

Alex and Anna play a game. Alex picks n distinct real numbers a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>,… ,a<sub>n</sub> and a bijective function
f : {1,2,…,n} -> {a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>,… ,a<sub>n</sub>}. Anna, which only knows the number n, has to guess the function. For that, at each step, she picks a proper subset A of the domain and Alex tells her the elements of the set f(A). Find the minimum number of steps after which Anna can determine the function f.

I've encountered this problem in a math magazine and I have no idea how to solve it, so I was hoping that you could give me a hint. I first thought of an induction proof but i don't know how to start.

Comment: Assume $n = 16$, and let $A_k$ denote the set $\{k, k+1, \cdots, k + 7\} ~: k \in \{1,2,3,\cdots,9\}.$  Then, it looks like $(9)$ is an upper bound on the number of necessary steps, since your proper subsets could be $A_1, A_2, \cdots, A_9.$  This is as far as my thinking takes me.  Actually, it is unclear to me whether, in the given strategy, the $A_9$ turn is actually necessary.

Comment: Re previous comment, $A_9$ is demonstrably unnecessary, since $A_9$ is implied by $A_1$.  So, the upper bound is reduced to $(8)$.

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you for your strategy suggestion, it was very helpful!  But I'm not sure I understand how A9 is implied by A1. How did you determine that?

Comment: Since $f$ is a bijection, $A_1$ and $A_9$ must be two disjoint subsets whose union is $A$.  So $A_9$ is the *complement* of $A_1$, with respect to $A$.

Comment: @user2661923 But Anna doesn't know f(A) / the image of the function, she only knows the number n at the beginning of the game. So, I think 9 would be the upper bound.

Comment: Very good point; I totally overlooked that.  So, my reasoning was false, and my analysis does not imply that $(8)$ is an upper bound.  However, for $n=16$, this does not mean that $(9)$ is the minimum number of steps required, but only that $(9)$ is an upper bound for the minimum number of steps required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to prove that this is optimal but I have a method that can determine the function in $\lfloor log_{2}(n) \rfloor + 1$ steps.

First, convert the numbers in $\{1,2,\dots, n\}$ into their binary representation, e.g., $9_{10} = 1001_{2}$ where the subscript represents the base of the number system used. Then at step $j$ you select the numbers that have a $1$ at the $j$-th position on the binary representation of the number, e.g., $11_{10} = 1011_{2}$ you select the number $11_{10}$ on the first, second and fourth step. For example, if $n=16$ the binary represenation of the numbers $1,\dots, n$ are
\begin{align}
1_{10} &= 00001_{2} \\
2_{10} &= 00010_{2} \\
3_{10} &= 00011_{2} \\
4_{10} &= 00100_{2} \\
5_{10} &= 00101_{2} \\
6_{10} &= 00110_{2} \\
7_{10} &= 00111_{2} \\
8_{10} &= 01000_{2} \\
9_{10} &= 01001_{2} \\
10_{10} &= 01010_{2} \\
11_{10} &= 01011_{2} \\
12_{10} &= 01100_{2} \\
13_{10} &= 01101_{2} \\
14_{10} &= 01110_{2} \\
15_{10} &= 01111_{2} \\
16_{10} &= 10000_{2} \\
\end{align}
and the sequence of guesses are:
\begin{align}
\text{step 1: }& A=\{1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15\} \\
\text{step 2: }& A=\{2,3,6,7,10,11,14,15\} \\
\text{step 3: }& A=\{4,5,6,7,12,13,14,15\} \\
\text{step 4: }& A=\{8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15\} \\
\text{step 5: }& A=\{16\}
\end{align}
As an example, let us assume that after our guesses Alex told us that number $x$ appears in steps 2,3,4 and not in steps 1 and 5. Since $f$ is a bijection this can only occur if the number we selected was in steps 2,3,4 and not in steps 1 and 5. We can uniquely determine that number to be $01110_{2} = 13_{10}$ and therefore we know that $f(13_{10}) = x$. The same reasoning holds for all the other numbers. The number of steps needed is the number of digits of $n$ in base $2$ which is equal to $\lfloor log_{2}(n) \rfloor + 1$.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very clever solution! I would never have thought of converting the number in base 2.

Comment: So, to make it clear, using the above steps, f(11) would be f(A1) ∩ f(A2) ∩ f(A4) \ ( f(A3) ∪ f(A5)), because, converted in base 2, 11 has 1s on positions 1, 2 and 4 and 0s on positions 3 and 5 (counted from the right). Am I right?

Comment: @user874094 yes, that is correct.